# Checking if the user did login in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication

I am using root controller for changing my storyboard by using Window:

```
  Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener() { auth, user in
        if user != nil {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "main")
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

The code above is in the func application in-app delegate

The problem is that it does not go to my storyboard with the identifier "main"

Question: how to change VC if in my case the storyboard's identifier is "main", when the user is logged in

My code above is not working(

Comment: What is your question?  Is it about how to present a view controller or is it about how to check if a particular user (or current user?) is logged in?

Comment: My question is that how to present another VC, if the user is logged in

Comment: Telling us "is not working" is vague. *What* specifically is not working. For example; your question states *it does not go to my storyboard with the identifier "main"* which may be the issue because you are loading the storyboard *Main* here `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)` not *main*. (I am just using that as an example) Did you step through your code line by line to determine which line is not behaving as expected? If so, which line?

Comment: @Jay First sorry if it is confusing

So, "main" is the identifier of my storyboard (I changed to other identifiers of storyboards just to check if the problem with "main") - it is not, others has the same result


Regarding lines 
//
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
//
these ones are not working 

Basically, it should change the root controller

Comment: You are asking two separate questions.  Pick one.

Comment: I want to change my VC to another in my example it is "main" (it is just an example identifier). 


I am  not asking different questions, the code above is similar to the changing VC if the user logged in  like here https://www.raywenderlich.com/3-firebase-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: So it's actually several different questions so let's nail it down to one. Your question title is *Checking if the user did login in firebase*. But it doesn't appear you're asking about that, so that's not the question. It appears you're asking how to instantiate different controllers depending on the user status - either already authenticated or not authenticated. If that's the case, you're actually asking how to work with viewControllers which is unrelated to Firebase. We are trying to help but need to know the actual question - can you update the *question* please?